# Removing redirect link malware

Tags: malware

I have Xiaomi Mi3 and it's not rooted. Every time I open a web page, *both on mobile data and WiFi, and even with different browsers*, I get redirected to other pages with ads and pages like this:

```
http://mobiles.digital/IT/Sweepstake/LP/index.php?voluumdata=vid..00000004-4837-403c-8000-000000000000__vpid..ca8d4800-fd5d-11e4-88ba-7eef5f3eb726__caid..5422e033-3dc6-4996-b128-7bf07d491d19__rt..R__lid..19777e53-9ce2-45a2-8073-ce9466d65506__oid1..7756b6f2-77b0-4db4-8d79-0faa4854c67f__oid2..b504e00f-54b7-4fd2-99de-09a0e4919980__var1..425682__rd..www%5C.%5Cyouradexchange%5C.%5Ccom&SiteID=425682
```

I have tried:

- Many antivirus (including AVG premium app which was free this weekend on Amazon app shop)
- Factory reset: inside settings on my phone
- Hard reset: deleted cache and installed app.
- AdBlocker plus.

But nothing worked.

Here's the installed apps on my phone: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2cFQ2PnOtfNT0NsMnZJY1NiT1U&usp=sharing

Comment: 1) Is your phone rooted? 2) Have you tried an adblocker? 3) Can you share screenshots of the apps installed (if no privacy concern exists)? 4) Does it happen on Wifi , mobile data, or both?

Comment: 1)No 2)Yes, ive tried adblock but 3) i'll share it asap 4) both thanks for good question gonna edit my post asap

Comment: Are you going to share screenshots (mentioned in the comment)?

Comment: For me the album link don't work even logged into google plus. Are you sure it's public?

Comment: @FedericoPonzi I agree with *user3344236*. The permission to view the album by others isn't granted yet; Please change it to public.

Comment: updated with gdrive

Comment: It seems you're infected with YourAdExchange malware (note the URL at the end). However, I still haven't found any clue to clean it on Android.

Comment: Andrew T. this can be a false assumption also. I think the correct title should be: removing redirect link malware on Android phone. :)

Comment: @user3344236 fair enough since I couldn't find any clue related to that malware on Android.

Comment: Recently there's [a similar issue related to YourAdExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109816/how-to-stop-my-android-device-from-being-spammed-in-the-browser-as-well-as-in-th). I'm not really sure if your case is the same as that, but you might be interested to try the answer before flashing the ROM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to get more information to help. Could you show the MIUI version of your phone? See it in Settings -> About Phone -> MIUI version. If you can use adb in your PC? I think It will be helpful if you can show the output of PC command "adb shell pm list packages" and the output of "adb shell ls -l /system/app /system/priv-app"

By the way, if a factory reset can not resolve the problem you can try a full ota update which will reformat the system partition. To do full ota update: Click the Updater app, and then click the menu button in the right top, then click the "Download update" item. !Remember to backup your files!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The MIUI version is 4.10.17,  android version 4.4.4 . When i try to Download update i get a "no update available "message, so i can't do it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: 4.10.17 is a beta version and is rooted by default. Did you get it from the MIUI's official website? (en.miui.com)

Comment: I actually brought it from xiaomi on Amazon

Comment: I think you can try to download a full ROM package to do an update and then do a factory reset. The official download website: http://en.miui.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) free  and [Malwarebytes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware) , one after another (not 2 installed in the same time).

Try to move the app masked as **com.securitycore.miui_t** to SD card, then scan your phone again.

**Reasoning:**

I removed an "insane" pop-up linker (no matter what browser I used) which, instead acting like an activity by default (a malware activity) just used text displayed on webpage ( reading html meta tags ) and added link with advertorial content (manipulating content by adding div contents) or opening random links even if I visited “legit” and “clean” sites.

I recommended Avast for it's heuristic engine (IMHO better than AVG). Malware bytes actually marks threats and help remove some “non-detectable” adware (details about heuristic engine *vs.* databases containing signatures of viral code is out of the scope here).

Having in fact an extended experience with those kind of threats, my advice is a first step for taking countermeasures against this malicious object (script). I also see the user has a strange object acting like overwriting content or redirecting page.

So, after scanning with those 2 tools, the user may come back telling: none worked. How we must interpret this second problem? I think the key in this case is thinking about “where” antivirus and other products used did not look. As obvious, there can be two major places: `/data/` or `/system` root folders. So, in case we still have troubles after scanning with some tools the solution which comes to mind is to go in `/data/` or `/system` folders and manually remove application which we suspect (browser application, in our case).

Being aware the user has a non-rooted device, a simple solution is to use another browser after deleting/uninstall browser app which caused trouble. I hope the user has original ROM by Xiaomi and not a "modified" one (there were rumors about malware packed inside 'Xioami' counterfeit rooms, even if the device looks legit).

Readings for reference:

- [[Android] Android malware found on Google Play with millions of downloads](http://en.miui.com/thread-82712-1-1.html)
- [Popular Xiaomi Phone Could Put Data at Risk](https://bluebox.com/technical/popular-xiaomi-phone-could-put-data-at-risk/)

Comment: From the settings page of the app, i cant find move to sd options. Seems like Xiaomi dosen't support move to sd natively. http://en.miui.com/thread-12681-1-1.html

Comment: Try to disable/delete/uninstall com.securitycore.miui_t (do not reboot phone) and see if browser still acts strange. I think it should be enabled again on reboot. I doubt  Malware bytes and Avast did not find anything strange...

Comment: Can't disable/delete/unistall it! Removed the data but the adware is still there :(