# How to stop my Android device from being spammed in the browser as well as in the application?

Tags: applications, browser, malware, spam

Recently I have downloaded two games:

1. Deer Hunter
2. PreHistoric Worm

But after that I have my browser which keeps redirecting me to `http://ad.adsmatte.com`

It is happening every time I load the page – after few seconds, it automatically gets redirected to this AdsMatte and doesn't go back to the previous page, even if I press the <kbd>Back</kbd> key.

In an application like WebMd, when I load the app, after few seconds it is covered with a full screen ad whereas it used to display the options menu. This is blocking my view and I cannot see what is being displayed by the application.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>The WebMd app which is showing an "Update Your Browser" message with a "Install Now" link to Play Store (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I don't have Opera and it still tells me to update my Opera browser.

I closed the application and retried it, and again it is displayed with some "Warning your HM1S is affected with Virus" and starts vibrating.

**Note:** Please avoid anything like this post suits well on MIUI/forum, I have already asked there and got a very immature answer as to disable Java Scripts even after seeing my below screenshot.

[Update]
I have tried using mobile data and now it does not redirect so it's more of the modern problem the app are clean

Comment: which browser do you use..opera or chrome or something else?

Comment: It is UC Browser with Ad Blocker,Pop blocker enabled

Comment: your device may not have been affected by any kind of virus. i have used UC browser and it suggested to download unwanted apps and alerts like these..so i suggest you use chrome or opera browser..the redirection problem might be due to an extension(add-on) you have installed diable or remove all your addons and reset the browser settings..

Comment: For a starter, please take a look at our [malware tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/malware/info) and follow the first-aid links. As you already described the issue started after installing those apps: Have you tried to remove them? Did that help? And btw: where did you install those apps from? // @Lucky no such thing like a "virus" on Android ;) But malware indeed, yes. Which is why I've added the `malware` tag to the question.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 4 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the same problem on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/626156/331791), this is not OS-dependent, but an attack to the router. Try hard reset the router.

> This does not appear to be an OS related issue. I would recommend you to read this http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-AdsMatte-spam-popups-and-ads
>
> Basically it is an attack on/via your router. You should hard reset it. A lot of computers on my intranet got affected. I got rid of it that way.

If it still fails, from [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/89749/59741), try checking & fixing the DNS address both on router *and Android device*.

> If your router is affected and you're facing different issues on your devices (Android has no ads, computer does) may check/change your DNS settings on both devices and on the router.
>
> I think your Android phone uses a different DNS server as your PC. Your PC probably uses your router as DNS Server (e.g. `196.168.1.1`) and your Android uses a 3rd party DNS like Google (`8.8.8.8`, `4.4.4.4`) or OpenDNS. For this behaviour check: [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/767172/dns-server-at-router-level-vs-computer-level)
>
> To clean up your router, you may have a look at: 
>   [this answer on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87102/can-i-have-a-virus-adware-in-my-router/87106#87106)

To check DNS settings on Android:

1. Open **Settings - Wi-Fi**
2. Long-press the access point, select **Modify network**
3. Turn on **Advanced options**
4. Change IP settings to **Static**
5. Check/set the **DNS 1** & **DNS 2** to Google DNS (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) or other trusted DNS server.