# Prevent redirection on chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

Whenever I select anything I have Google on Chrome, I always get redirected to another spam like site or says my phone is infected. I have an antivirus software which doesn't pick up any virus infected on my phone.

Others suggest blocking JavaScript, which works but you cannot view any site or video after. Is there a way to prevent always being redirected?

Comment: Related: [Removing redirect link malware](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/109694/16575) / [How to stop my Android device from being spammed in the browser as well as in the application?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/109816/16575) / [Android browser redirecting malware sites](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/114360/16575) / [Malware on LG G3 redirecting all browsers](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/103629/16575) / [more](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=malware+redirect)

Answer (score 1):

Try anyone of these:

- Root the phone. Use [Adblock plus](https://update.adblockplus.org/latest/adblockplusandroid.apk) app. Rooting voids warranty.
- Use [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) with Adblock extention installed. This doesn't require rooting.
- Use [Adblock browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adblockplus.browser). Rooting isn't necessary here.
- Use [UC mini browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uc.browser.en&hl=en) with Speed mode enabled. Browsing experience will be deteriorated.
  I recommend second method the most. Please don't ask for links. Everything can be found using Google.

Comment: @Firelord - I know you would reply before OP ;-) Links added...